# Text encoding of Protocol Buffers string fields

Tags: c++, character-encoding, protocol-buffers

If a C++ program receives a Protocol Buffers message that has a [Protocol Buffers `string` field](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#strings), which is represented by a `std::string`, what is the encoding of text in that field? Is it UTF-8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Protobuf strings are always valid `UTF-8` strings.

See the [Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar):

> A string must always contain UTF-8 encoded or 7-bit ASCII text.

(And ASCII is always also valid UTF-8.)

Not all protobuf implementations enforce this, but if I recall correctly, at least the Python library refuses to decode non-unicode strings.